# How can I open another file index.html, depending on the width of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my problem.

I've got finished page (html + css + js), but I want to do a mobile version, with other html files, another index.html and css file. What do I need to add the code to the main page, that when i open site on device with screen width less than 800 pixels it will launching the mobile version?

Comment: Do you need the code imported, or would a redirect to `/m/index.html` work?  Also, are you hoping that if I open the page on my computer at width 1440px, and resize down to 700px width, it will switch which mode I'm on (dynamically)?

Comment: I forgot to write, I want redirect to /m/index.html

Comment: So yeah, use .htaccess: http://ohryan.ca/2011/01/21/modern-mobile-redirect-using-htaccess/

Comment: Tip: If you want the mobile version to be exactly like the desktop version, but smaller and usable on the mobile device, then you may want to look into "responsive web design" and "CSS frameworks" such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) **instead of** creating a separate website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your onload:

```
if(window.innerWidth < 800{
    window.location = '/m/index.html';
}
```

or (this is as cross-browser)

```
if(window.screen.width < 800{
    window.location = '/m/index.html';
}
```

Comment: Note the missing )

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the answer you want, however this script will re-direct the user if they are utilizing a touch screen device (i.e. Phone, tablet)

```
<script>
    if( 'ontouchstart' in window ){
        window.location = 'mobile/index.html';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your mobile version on subdomain or subfolder and add JavaScript mobile user detection and redirect them to mobile page

https://github.com/sebarmeli/JS-Redirection-Mobile-Site